# Is there a global map of aviation waypoints?

Tags: navigation, radio-navigation

Is there such a map or database available to the public?

Comment: I doubt there is a globally-maintained map. The closest you can get is Navigraph's (and other similar services) database, or "local" maps maintained by individual FIRs.

Comment: There's no one authority that maintains a global database. You have to rely on a service that consolidates the data from the various authorities. I often refer to [Skyvector](https://skyvector.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are searching for is [SkyVector](http://SkyVector.com)

Its a web-map where you can see waypoints, NDBS, DMES, FREQUENCIES, ETC

Answer (score 1):

Each country publishes an AIP that, among many other things, lists all their waypoints and coordinates. Note that an AIP is formatted as a written document, not as a database. Some also publish databases, but they each use a different format and may require payment to access.

There are commercial services that collect all these databases (or parse the AIPs if needed), convert them into a common format and merge them into a single database—and repeat that process every time any country releases updates to their AIP. Obviously, that's a lot of work, so nobody is doing it for free.